# Solving Logical Questions Using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to solve a problem for a fun work exercise showing that SQL can be used to solve it.  It is a puzzle that goes as follows:

*Successfully navigating the waters during sea voyages is a challenging task.  A captain’s most important decision is selecting the right crew for the voyage.  A mix of different skill sets are required to sail the ship efficiently, navigate to the destination, and fish for food along the way.
Table 1 shows a list of crew members that are available for you to hire for the voyage.  Each crew member demands a salary for the voyage and has different skill levels of Fishing, Sailing, and Navigation.
In order for your journey to be successful, you must have a cumulative skill of 15 or more in each of the three skill categories from all of your chosen crew members.  You may choose as many crew members as you like.
Question:  What is the minimum achievable cost for the voyage?"*

I would say I am what I would consider an intermediate to advanced (depending on the situation) SQL user.

Not asking for an answer per-say but I have thought about the best way to solve and I was first thinking using a `WHILE` loop in some way.  I have create a table to hold the data and added a 'salary_ranking' column (below).  I am curious if anyone has any tips or suggestions on routes to go?  I would like to use something I have never used before but also am trying to get to the most efficient answer.

Here is the data (I added the last column):

```
NAME       FISHING     SAILING     NAVIGATION  SALARY      SALARY_RANK
---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Amy        3           5           1           46000       3
Bill       1           2           5           43000       2
Carl       3           4           2           47000       4
Dan        4           3           1           36000       1
Eva        4           2           2           43000       2
Fred       1           3           4           55000       5
Greg       3           1           5           68000       8
Henry      5           4           2           64000       7
Ida        3           3           3           60000       6

(9 rows affected)
```

Comment: Well I would definitely cross out `while-loop` and `database-cursor` from your tags if you want to make it interesting.  Its going to be a CTE of some sort I suspect. Interesting question.

Comment: thank you - and i did remove those tags, I am trying to remember not to always use what I think and I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a CTE version, where I first create test data, then run a recursive query, using a MaxID to prevent it doing all the permutations.

```
declare @t table(Id int, NAME varchar(10), FISHING int, SAILING int, NAVIGATION int, SALARY int)

insert @t values (1,'Amy',3,5,1,46000)
    ,(2,'Bill',1,2,5,43000 )
    ,(3,'Carl',3,4,2,47000)
    ,(4,'Dan',4,3,1,36000)
    ,(5,'Eva',4,2,2,43000)
    ,(6,'Fred',1,3,4,55000)
    ,(7,'Greg',3,1,5,68000)
    ,(8,'Henry',5,4,2,64000)
    ,(9,'Ida',3,3,3,60000 )

;with cte as (
    select convert(varchar(1000),name) as crew, fishing, sailing, navigation, salary, ID as MaxID from @t
    union all
    select convert(varchar(1000),cte.crew+', '+ t.name), cte.fishing+t.fishing, cte.sailing+t.sailing, cte.navigation+t.navigation, cte.salary+t.salary, t.ID
    from @t t
    join cte on t.ID>cte.MaxID
    )
select top 1 crew,fishing,sailing,navigation,salary
from cte 
where fishing>=15 and sailing>=15 and navigation>=15 
order by salary
```

result is:

```
crew                            fishing sailing navigation  salary  
Amy, Bill, Carl, Greg, Henry    15      16      15          268000
```

Comment: very interesting - I haven't used recursive CTE but that makes a ton of sense!

Comment: Just trying to answer the `I would like to use something I have never used before` part of your question :)

Comment: sorry to ask another question - I am trying to make sure I understand that recursive part as I learned a bit of a different way  - is the JOIN condition you used (t.ID > cte.ID) essentially going through every combo of crew?  I am trying to get a better understanding of how it works.  My understanding was the first part of a recursive CTE 'passes' values to the recursive part which executes until it hits NULL - this is very interesting

Comment: really it is the JOIN that is the part I haven't used or seen before: JOIN cte ON t1.ID > cte.MaxID - I've never seen a JOIN on a boolean and am curious how that works

Comment: My initial version used `join cte on cte.crew not like '%'+t.name+'%'` to exclude any rows already containing the name. The result of that was all combinations and permutations, from memory almost a million rows. Worked fine, but was a little slow. By adding the ID and using `t.ID>cte.ID` I could eliminate all the permutations, and just leave the combinations. Either of them gives the correct answer. If you want to experiment, see this fiddle: `http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e818d/3`. And BTW, a join condition can be anything, doesnt need to be an =.